# It goes extremely slow for my website to make my changes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that I need to make some changes on. But my changes takes a long time to change.

http://www.postwork.se

I want to select `display: none;` at some social items in the header, but the changes don't want to take any effect. What do I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to hide social icon

```
## for facebook 
.w-socials-item.facebook {
  dispaly: none;
}

## for twitter
.w-socials-item.twitter {
  dispaly: none;
}

## for google
.w-socials-item.google {
  dispaly: none;
}

## for linkedin
.w-socials-item.linkedin {
  dispaly: none;
}

## for hide all social icon
.w-socials-item {
  dispaly: none;
}
```

you already use WP Super Cache plugin, you need clear Cache.